# Call to undefined method Employee::insert_employee()

Tags: codeigniter

**controller**

```
         elseif ($param1 == 'add') {
                       $data['employee_deparatments'] = $this->department->get_departments($fldCompanyStringID);

        if ($this->input->post('viewType') == 'add' && $this->input->post('submit')) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fldUserBranchName', 'Branch Name', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', validation_errors());
            } else {

                $this->employee->insert_employee($fldCompanyStringID);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
class M_employee extends CI_Model {

    function get_employee ($fldCompanyStringID){
    }
}
```

Comment: Your model don't have `insert_employee` function, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a model with file name `M_employee` but in **controller** you called employee.

First load the model in **controller** :

```
$this->load->model('M_employee');
```

Next call the **function** by this type:

```
$this->M_employee->insert_employee($fldCompanyStringID);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also add namespace for the model ,ilke

```
First load the model in controller :
```

**$this->load->model('M_employee','employee');**

Next call the function by this type:
$this->employee->insert_employee($fldCompanyStringID);

no need to edit the controller function

Comment: I also called this function before .... but error is same "Call to undefined method Employee::insert_employee()" What the reason ? But first answer is work

Comment: function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('example');
}

Comment: You should call like this